# Why the recycler view doesn't work with load more functionality?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When execute code that time, null pointer coming, I can't understand what to do next?

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout    
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         tools:context="com.siliconinfo.loadmoredemo.MainActivity">

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/openFragment"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Click to open" />

             <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/contain"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:background="@color/grey_dark"
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

fragment_product.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/filterSortLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@color/white_dim_filter"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/filterProductLsit"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_filter_icon"
              android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
              android:text="@string/filter_text"
              android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
              android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_subheader" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/sortProductList"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
              android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_sort_icon"
              android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
              android:text="@string/sort_text"
              android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
              android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_subheader" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/gridListToggle"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:src="@mipmap/gri_view_icon" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="@color/skyblue_view" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/noDataMessageText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/no_item_found"
         android:visibility="gone" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@mipmap/bestsellers_mainbg">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarItemsRecycler"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/productListRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white_dim_details"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

      <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarItemsRecyclerOuter"
            style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

row layout set in adapter

row_gridviewtype.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/bestsellers_pro_listbg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

               <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/progressBarItems"
               style="?android:progressBarStyleSmall"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageview"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/row_accessories_grid_width"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/row_accessories_grid_width_hight"
              android:src="@mipmap/no_image_available"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
     </FrameLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/productNameText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:textSize="@dimen/text_header" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/productPriceText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:textColor="@color/skyblue_view"
         android:textSize="@dimen/text_header" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/productRegularPriceText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_5"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_5"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:textColor="@color/grey"
         android:textSize="@dimen/text_header" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is progressbar , load below the recyclerview, when scroll a recycler view.

row_load.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

DesktopFragment cointain list

```
    public class DeskPortTprtOurFvtAromaThrpyFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static String TAG ="DeskPortTprtOurFvtAromaThrpyFragment";
    private View mRoot;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private Typeface mTypefaceBold,mTypefaceSemiBold,mTypefaceRegular;
    private RecyclerView mProductListRecyclerView;
    privateArrayList<ProductListResponseModel>
    mProductListResponseModelArrayList = new   ArrayList<ProductListResponseModel>();
    private ProgressBar mProgressBarRecycleView, mProgressBarOuter;
    private boolean mVieType = true;
    private String
    mProductResponsePortableStr,mProductResponseDesktopStr,
    mProductResponseTopRatedStr,mProductResponseOurFavouriteStr,
    mProductResponseAromaTherapyStr,  mCategoryStr;
    String pageNumber = "", shortValue = "", storeId = "", shopByFrom= "", shopByTo = "";
    private TextView mFilterTextView, mSortTextView;
    private ArrayList<String> categoryID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mCAtegoryIdFilter = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String shopByFrom1 = "", shopByFrom2 = "", shopByFrom3="",  shopByTo1 = "", shopByTo2 = "", shopByTo3 = "";
    View.OnClickListener mFilterClickListener;
    private String mFilterTag = "NO";
    private boolean zeroPosition = false, onePosition = false, secondPositon = false, thirdPosition = false;
    String pageNo = "0";
    private ImageView mToggleViewListGridImageView;
    Bundle productID;
    ProductListAdaptr mProductListAdaptr;
    private boolean loading = true;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container,false);
    initView();
    return mRoot;
    }
    private void initView() {
    mPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.PREF_NAME,   Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    mToggleViewListGridImageView = (ImageView)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.gridListToggle);
     ((ImageView)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.gridListToggle)).setOnClickListener(this);

    mProductListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.productListRecyclerView);
    mFilterTextView = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.filterProductLsit);
    mSortTextView = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.sortProductList);
    ((TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.filterProductLsit)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.sortProductList)).setOnClickListener(this);

    Logger.e("TAG", "Product ID is : " + categoryID);
    mProgressBarRecycleView = (ProgressBar) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.progressBarItemsRecycler);
    mProgressBarOuter = (ProgressBar) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.progressBarItemsRecyclerOuter);
    categoryID.add("10");
    mProductListAdaptr = new ProductListAdaptr(getContext(), mProductListResponseModelArrayList, mProductClickListener, 0);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mProductListAdaptr.setLoadMoreListener(new ProductListAdaptr.OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            mProductListRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int index = mProductListResponseModelArrayList.size() - 1;
                    loadMore(index);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    load(0);
    }

    private void load(int index) {
    getProductList(categoryID, String.valueOf(index), "", "", "", "",  "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    private void loadMore(int index) {

    }


    private void showProductList() {
    ((LinearLayout)  mRoot.findViewById(R.id.filterSortLayout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((TextView)  mRoot.findViewById(R.id.noDataMessageText)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (mVieType == true) {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    ProductListRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(newDefaultItemAnimator());
    mProductListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new    ProductListAdaptr(getContext(), mProductListResponseModelArrayList,   mProductClickListener, 0));
    } else if (mVieType == false) {
    final GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new   GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mProductListRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new  DefaultItemAnimator());
    mProductListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new   ProductListAdaptr(getContext(), mProductListResponseModelArrayList,  mProductClickListener, 1));
    }
     mProductListResponseModelArrayList.addAll(mProductListResponseModelArrayList);
    mProductListAdaptr.notifyDataChanged();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mProductClickListener = new   View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (int) v.getTag();
    }
    };

    private void getProductList(ArrayList<String> categoryId, String  pagenumber, String shopByFrom1, String shopByTo1,
                            String shopByFrom2, String shopByTo2,   String shopByFrom3, String shopByTo3, String shortValue, String storesID,  String FilterTag) {
    String categoryListString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryId.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            categoryListString = categoryId.get(i).toString();
        else
            categoryListString = categoryListString + ", " +  categoryId.get(i).toString();
    }
    if (Utils.checkInternetConnection(getActivity())) {
        final ProdcutListRequestTask mProductListRequestTask = new  ProdcutListRequestTask(getActivity());
        mProductListRequestTask.setAsyncCallListener(new   AsyncCallListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Object response) {
        mProductListResponseModelArrayList  (ArrayList<ProductListResponseModel>) response;
        ((LinearLayout)mRoot.findViewById(R.id.filterSortLayout)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBarOuter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBarRecycleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (mProductListResponseModelArrayList != null) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "DektoPportaOurFavouriteFragment  : " + mProductListResponseModelArrayList.size());
        }
        if (response == null) return;
                if (mProductListResponseModelArrayList == null || mProductListResponseModelArrayList.size() == 0) {
                    ((TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.noDataMessageText)).setTypeface(mTypefaceBold);
                    ((TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.noDataMessageText)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((LinearLayout) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.filterSortLayout)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return;
                }

                showProductList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorReceived(String error) {
                mProgressBarOuter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        mProductListRequestTask.execute(categoryListString, pagenumber, shopByFrom1, shopByTo1, shopByFrom2, shopByTo2, shopByFrom3, shopByTo3,
                shortValue, storesID, FilterTag);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_internet), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mProgressBarOuter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: 1) "I" is always capital on English. 2) I've tried to reformulate your title, but it is still not very clear. If you want good answers, it is important to have an easily understable title, and not a tag cloud. 3) If you want debugging help, give the minimal needed code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: It is very difficult to provide assistance without a [mcve]

Comment: @peterh my problem is solved, but getting one issue, my functionality have 2 button, grid & list , when click on grid display grid layout & click list display list, when i change layout that time load more not work other wise work very well, send me your email id , i will send my code, to solve this problem if possible,,,

Comment: @Hitesh Ask this as a new question. And don't forget to use correct title, and [correct spelling](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370).

Answer (score 0):

use this, working for me.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                        if (hasMore && !(hasFooter())) {
                            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                            //position starts at 0
                            if (layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == layoutManager.getItemCount() - 2) {
                                new GetPostData().execute();
                            }
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                });
```

hope it will also help you.

Comment: look at this example it will help you https://codentrick.com/load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar/